# Definition of Lie derivatives of sections of natural vector bundles - product preservation needed?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, flows

Section 6.15 of *Natural Operations* by Kolár, Michor, and Slovak defines the Lie derivative of a section of a natural vector bundle along a vector field. Set-theoretically, the definition is clear. Just after, the authors assert the Lie derivative to be a *smooth* section. To see this for myself, I have tried to write it as a composite of smooth maps. However, there seems to be an obstacle without assuming the natural vector bundle is product-preserving.

**Question.** Is the Lie derivative of a section itself a *smooth* section also for non-product preserving natural vector bundles?

Below I give my description of the Lie derivative as a composite of smooth maps. First, a couple of details.

1. If $\vec v$ is a vector field I will write $X\times \mathbb R\supset \mathfrak D(\vec v)\overset{\exp \vec v}{\longrightarrow} X$ for its flow map. The map $\mathfrak D(\vec v)\to X\times \mathbb R$ given by $(x,t)\mapsto (\exp \vec v(x,t),t)$ is a $C^\infty$ isomorphism $\mathfrak D(\vec v)\cong \mathfrak D(-\vec v)$.
2. If we have a morphism $f$ of submersions over $Z$ (commutative triangle with top side $f:X\times (a,b)\to Y$) whose domain is $X\times (a,b)$ then its (relative) time-derivative is the smooth lift $X\times (a,b)\to \mathrm T_{Y/Z}$ defined by the formula $\partial_tf(x_0,t_0)=\mathrm T(x_0,0,t_0,1)$. Here $\mathrm T_{Y/Z}$ denotes the vertical bundle.
3. In particular, if $Y\to Z$ is a vector bundle, then its vertical bundle is canonically isomorphic to the first projection $Y\times_ZY\to Y$, so composing with the *second* projection allows to interpret the time-derivative as valued in $Y$.

Now the diagrams defining the Lie derivative. $F$ denotes a natural vector bundle functor. The problem lies in the first diagram. Using the notation of *Natural Operations*, I want to define $ (\exp\vec v)^\ast s$ as the composite by "fattening up" the section $s$. However, without product preservation it seems this "fattening up" is not available as e.g in the case of $F=\mathrm T$ the tangent bundle.
[image]
If the above diagram is granted, the second one is as follows. The lengthy composite applies remarks (2,3) to interpret the time-derivative as taking values in $FX$.
[image]

Finally, since $X\times \left\{ 0 \right\} \subset \mathfrak D(\vec v)$, the time-derivative at zero is defined on $X$ and is smooth as the restriction of a smooth map. This is the Lie derivative, exhibited as a smooth section $X\to FX$.

Am I missing something? Is the "fattened section" unnecessary?